# Wrong versionName from Manifest

Tags: android, apk, version, android-manifest

I am trying to update my app apk to its version 3.2 (using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2).
As always, I update the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionCode="82"
    android:versionName="3.2" >
...
```

Yet, the generated apk has the old versionName 3.1. The apk is the new one with new stuff, and the string "3.1" does not exist in the whole project folder, nor in the build.gradle file (which makes no reference to the verionName or versionCode). The only problem seems to be that the versionName is not updated.

Yet, after I build the apk through "Build > Make Module...", the two files

```
./build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/com/floritfoto/apps/riobas/BuildConfig.java
./build/outputs/apk/debug/output-metadata.json
```

show respectively

```
public static final String VERSION_NAME = "3.1";
"versionName": "3.1"
```

After a "Build > Clean project" this disappears, but then it come back when building the apk.

Who is doing this??

I tried invalidating caches without luck.

**EDIT**

I found the culprit. Following an Adroid Studio suggestion, I have set this week in the global gradle.properties file the option

```
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true
```

Reversing it to `false` fixed the issue.

Isn't this a bug in Android Studio??